# scripts in ~/bin don't work when connecting through ssh

Tags: ssh, scripts

I have some script in my `$HOME/bin` folder.
When I access my machine remotely I can't use them and I can't understand
why. They work just fine when I'm in front of my remote computer.

I think it might have something to do with the `.bashrc` file. The `PATH` is set with

```
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin
export PATH
```

it seems correct to me though.

I have also tried to copy the file in the `/usr/bin` folder logging out and in again,
but still I can't manage to use my script.

If I go in the `~/bin` directory and type `./myscript` the script work (it is just that I need to run it from different folders where I have some files to process).

Comment: Have you tried whether the PATH is really set? `echo $PATH`

Comment: It just came to my mind.. and I came back to write that $PATH is actually not set. I couldn't read the answer 1 properly but my feeling is that it is the right one!

Comment: Is [my answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/147046/22949) the one you're having trouble reading? If so, please post comments to it, explaining the problem--I may be able to reply and/or edit my answer, for clarification. When you say `$PATH` is not actually set, do you mean that when you run `echo $PATH`, there is *no output at all*?

Comment: Eliahs answer looks right to me too - my comment was just there to make a fast check. A fast solution will however be to source the desired *rc-file like `. ~/.bashrc` or `source ~/.bashprofile`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is happening because when you log in via SSH, the shell you get is a **login shell**. In contrast, to use the terminology from the `bash` documentation, when you open a Terminal window in an already-started graphical login session, the shell you get is still an **interactive shell** but it is **not a login shell**.

From [`man bash`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/bash.1.html):

> When **bash** is invoked as an  interactive login shell, or as a
>   non-interactive  shell with the **--login** option, it first reads and
>   executes commands from the  file  `/etc/profile`, if that file exists.
>   After reading that file, it looks for `~/.bash_profile`,
>   `~/.bash_login`, and `~/.profile`, in that order, and reads and
>   executes commands from the first one that exists and is readable. The
>   **--noprofile** option may be used when the shell is started to inhibit this behavior.
>
> When a login shell exits, bash reads and executes commands from the
>   file `~/.bash_logout`, if it exists.
>
> When  an  interactive  shell that is not a login shell is started,
>   bash reads and executes commands from  `/etc/bash.bashrc` and
>   `~/.bashrc`, if these files exist. This may be inhibited by using the
>   **--norc** option. The **--rcfile** *file* option will force bash to read and  execute  commands from *file* instead of `/etc/bash.bashrc`
>   and `~/.bashrc`.

So you should check if you have any of these files:

- `~/.bash_profile`
- `~/.bash_login`
- `~/.profile`

If you do, then you should edit the first one you find and make it add `$HOME/bin` to your path. If you don't, create one of them for this purpose. (The best one to create is `~/.profile` since other shells will use that too.)

You almost certainly have `~/.profile`, since Ubuntu's default behavior is to create this with any new user account (including the first account, created when you install Ubuntu).

However, by default this file already contains the necessary lines to add your private `bin` directory to the `$PATH`:

```
# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
if [ -d "$HOME/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
fi
```

So it's a bit strange that this is not already working for you.

Depending on your needs, you might want to make `~/.profile` (or `~/.bash_login` or `~/.bash_profile`) call `~/.bashrc`:

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

But it would be even better to just include lines adding `$HOME/bin` to your `$PATH` in `~/.profile` (or `~/.bash_login` or `~/.bash_profile`), but **not** `~/.bashrc`. After all, if you do this for every login shell, it should also happen when you log in graphically, and be inherited by all your interactive shells that aren't login shells.

Comment: Thanks Eliah it worked (copying .bashrc into .bash_profile ). I can't understand properly the distinction between login shell, bash --login and so on though. What are the differences between the two kind of sessions? And how do I know wich session is invoked? (ok for ssh now I know..) Thanks again, you made my day!

Comment: @LucaCerone I recommend asking about what the differences are, and how to know what kind of shell you're in, as a separate question. This way, the answer will be maximally useful to others. (If you do this, you should feel free to comment here with a link to the new question, of course.)

Answer (score 0):

Simply put your config in **.bash_profile** file in home directory.

If you dont have it you can create it.

Comment: If `.profile` exists, which it probably does, then having a `.bash_profile` file will override `.profile`, causing it not to be used. This can cause problems. So if you're going to create a `.bash_profile` when `.profile` already exists, then the `.bash_profile` should contain the line `source ~/.profile`, so that the commands in `.profile` are still run. Alternatively, just add the commands to `.profile`.